# Picking selection just for first column (drives, folders, files) of a QFileSystemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qfilesystemmodel

In QFileSystemModel when selection is made on it, the return type is a `QList<QModelIndex>`. Is there a way to get selection just for the first column (the column with drives, folders and files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in particular selection, you should do next things for every QModelIndex in the list:

```
QFileSystemModel* p_fs_model;
...
foreach(QModelIndex index, whole_selection)
{
  QModelIndex first_column_index = p_fs_model->index(
      index->row(),
      0, /* first column index */
      index->parent()
  );
  ...
}
```